# how to reset the effect of bootstrap 5 text-muted

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 "text-muted" to grey out or dim the text.  On hover, I would like to undo this effect on the text.  I am able to make other effects for e.g. text decorations (underline) etc., on hover but not able to revert this effect. Is there a way to do this?

```css
li a {
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: to make it clear, i just want to disable the effect of "text-muted"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BS provides [the `.text-reset` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#reset-color) which does what you want.
Since you are compiling from source you can just extend the class:

```css
li a {
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    @extend .text-reset;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

### Or,

If you look at the style rule you can see what declarations are needed:

```css
.text-reset {
    --bs-text-opacity: 1;
    color: inherit!important;
}
```

And copy them to your rule:

```css
li a {
  color: white;
  &:hover {
    --bs-text-opacity: 1;
    color: inherit!important;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Arleigh,  this worked for me. However, @extend .text-reset  throws an error (and prompted me to use !optional and didn't work. just curious to know why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to revert the color of the link (like the color of the body) when hovering it

```css
.nav-item a:hover {
  color: $gray-900 !important; // It is #212529
}
```

If you will see the default color of the body in the variables.scss file it is `$gray-900`

```css
$body-color:                $gray-900 !default;
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit,   I think I might have to includes variables.scss file? because when I tried with $grey-900 didn't recognize. I replaced with color: #212529 didn't work either.  Thank you